# Grammar for a^n

Tags: computation-theory, automata-theory

Currently i am studying `computation theory` and i came up with this T - F question :

The following Grammar

```
S -> aS | Sa
```

produces the Language `{a^n | n>=1}`.

Well i do not know if we can say that, because this grammar does not halt. It just creates a bunch but it does accept nothing. It would surely be if we had an `ε` derivation rule.

It is exactly the same as having the following:

[image: example of automata that does accept nothing]

that never comes to a final state.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: If the following Grammar S -> aS | Sa produces the Language {a^n | n>=1}. If there is some theoretic point of view i am missing. I thought the question was pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Are you asking whether this grammar does indeed produce the language in question, or how it should be modified, in case it doesn't, to produce such language?

Comment: My knowledge in this field is a bit dusty, but it looks to me like it produces an infinite sequence of `a`s and would never terminate. So no, it doesn't produce the language in question.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo I believe the same. Thanks !